# How to deal with non-existent variables "reference before assignment"

Tags: python

I have some code that creates a variable if a certain condition is met:

```
if self.left: 
    left_count = self.left.isUnivalTree()
```

A few lines down I have the code:

```
if left_count and right_count: 
    total_count = right_count + left_count
```

This throws the following error:

`local variable 'left_count' referenced before assignment`

How do I get around this? Surely by saying `if left_count...` I account for the fact it may not

(This error is fixed by setting a default value to all the parameters in the function but I am just wondering if there is a simpler way around this as I need to set a default value for 5 parameters?)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning if `self.left` isn't `True`, try the below which will set a default of `None`:

```
left_count = self.left.isUnivalTree() if self.left else None
```

As per your question update, setting default parameters on the function is better, that's exactly what they are there for.

Comment: Thanks. That is perfect

Comment: @EML no problem. Please accept one of the answers listed so the question gets closed off.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
left_count = False
if self.left: left_count = self.left.isUnivalTree()
```

Just use the short circuiting behaviour of `and`:

```
left_count = self.left and self.left.isUnivalTree()
```

Answer (score 1):

If `isUnivalTree` returns a bool (which it should because of the name):

```
left_count = self.left and self.left.isUnivalTree()
```

Otherwise:

```
left_count = self.left.isUnivalTree() if self.left else None
```

Answer (score 0):

or catch the NameError

```
try:
    if left_count and right_count: total_count = right_count + left_count
except NameError:
    print('NameError catched')
    total_count = 0
```

or check if it is defined:

```
if 'left_count' in locals():
    print('left_count is defined')
```

it all depends on what fits best in your work flow